# Compile C# code extension at runtime

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

I have a system that compiles C# code at runtime. I would like the generated assemblies to be linked to the system itself. Here's some example code that I am using:

```
CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<String, String> { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } });
CompilerParameters compilerparams = new CompilerParameters();
compilerparams.GenerateExecutable = false;
compilerparams.GenerateInMemory = true;
foreach (string name in linkedreferences)
    compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(name + ".dll");
Assembly result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(compilerparams, filename);
```

What I would like to do is also add a reference to the main compiler program as well, so the newly compiled extension can use library routines from the compiler program.

```
Assembly entryasm = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
```

So the question is this: How do I add a reference to entryasm in the compiled Assembly result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
   compilerparams.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(entryasm.Location);
```